# Is scoping the controller's code under a custom view a good cocoa design pattern?

Tags: ios, cocoa, model-view-controller

As I was thinking about all the incarnations of MVC in Cocoa, I figured I could make a custom class for every View in the application and fill it with a datasource and delegate - stuff primarily considered for Controller.

This way, instead of having the infamous Massive-View-Controller, I could chop off pieces of code and put them in separate files - one class for one View - along with their datasource and delegates.

Is it a good idea, or what are the downsides?

Comment: I would suggest using the MVVM pattern, where the view controller is treated more like a view and the view model is doing most of the work. You can then reuse view controllers by injecting different view models as long as they conform to a certain protocol. Its something you can look into. I wouldn't be a fan of subclassing views but I know other devs that do it but it wouldn't be my style.

Comment: @matt_roo does the design I suggested fall under MVVM, or some other MVC umbrella?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that your idea sounds like you will end up with a bunch of bloated views instead of a bunch of bloated controllers.

What I'd suggest is to consider the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): an entity should have exactly one purpose or function. What's a view's function?

It's a representation, in code, of a region of the screen. That means it needs to do two things: draw to its area and register interactions with the area. Anything that's not absolutely essential to those two subtasks shouldn't be in the view class.

This is the idea of the "dumb view". It has no logic, no decisions to make. It just gets handed some data to render. And when it gets a tap or a click, it doesn't know what the input represents, or try to figure out what to do about it. It just knows the type of the interaction and tells another object.

That other object is the view's controller. A view controller's responsibility is to mediate between the view and the rest of the system. It gives the view its data. It also accepts messages from the view about input, and then reconfigures the view based on the result of those messages.

The view controller doesn't necessarily need to compute the result on its own, however. That's usually where view controllers start getting into "massive" trouble. The view controller should pick another object to help it get the new values that the interaction produces.

One possibility for this other object is the view model, in the [MVVM structure](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/mvvm/). The view model is a display-focused representation of the raw data for the view. It transforms the information in the model into whatever format the view needs, and re-transforms or updates the data in response to input from the view controller.

Another idea is to split that responsibility even more finely, using a [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/) arrangement. Here the formatting of the data is handled by a "Presenter", and the transformation of the data is the job of an "Interactor".

It's possible to get into architecture astronaut territory here; blindly applying a complex structure can bite you if a view's needs are inherently very simple. But even if you choose not to formally apply one of these alternative patterns, a view controller needs other objects. You will want "controllers" with other specific jobs, that get messages from the view controller and pass data back.

The important thing is to keep in mind the original idea I mentioned: strive to make each type **do one thing and do it well**. That will keep your classes focused; easy to read, understand, and think about; and testable.

Comment: Why is my approach not single responsibility compliant? Every UIView (and custom instance thereof) has a single one responsibilty - to take care of the given area on the screen. Whenever someone wants to change anything related to the given Control/button/View/whatevs, they find it in a single class. So I seems like it holds up against that holy principle, only the viewpoint of the responsibilities is different. What potential problems can I run into? In addition, in what regards its worse than Apple's original MVC?

Comment: You could also say that the application delegate's responsibility is to take care of a single application. Whenever someone wants to change anything related to the application's behavior, they find it in a single class. Why not do that?

Comment: Indeed, the issue is the granularity and how you define the responsibilities. Problem with using app delegate for everything is problematic because you essentially end up with an enormous file and won't help you make sense of the project. What problems I run into when I use the approach described in the question, that is, why is my way of breaking things down into responsibilities inferior to your way? (I believe it is, but I don't see WHY)

Answer (score 0):

View doesn't compute it's data, it just displays them. However if you have custom control it can have some logic to compute it's inner data to trigger value change inside model.

Your approach is an overkill with unnecessary code.

So you are facing a problem where you need to set some values of your custom NSView or custom NSControl (e.g. NSButton title).

Some of available MVC solutions:

1. set the value inside controller manually and call setNeedsDisplay method inside within view on the changed property.
2. set the model object as the property of view. However, this introduces tight coupling but still is ok (so the view has to
   know/import model class). +Include  update/refresh method within view
3. use bindings to nsobjectcontroller. You don't need to set Class of nsobjectcontroller (that is needed only if you need additional
   functionality for it like creating object automatically on add
   method).

MVC pattern reminder
View has target action mechanism which is triggered in controller. Controller updates model (nothing else!). Model then has to propagate that it has changed and controller should react to it. It shouldn't react in the target action.

With bindings you skip the target action but the latter remains

You can combine 2 and 3.

If you are beginner forget about VIPER pattern. MVVM can help you to reduce size of your controllers.

How to use binding with NSObjectController:

[image: Binding]

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Value.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSObjectController *objectController;
@property (strong) Value *value;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.value = [[Value alloc] init];
    self.objectController.content = [self value];
}

@end

@interface Value : NSObject

@property NSString *value1;
@property NSString *value2;
@property NSString *value3;

@end

#import "Value.h"

@implementation Value

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setValue1:@"Value1"];
        [self setValue2:@"Value2"];
        [self setValue3:@"Value3"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: If someone has an update/found a mistake I would be more than happy!

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to [unload View Controllers with Coordinator objects](http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/). Shortly: each task in the app is managed by a Coordinator object, which manages its View Controllers.

There is the main Coordinator object, that is retained by application delegate and that retains all other Controllers. All the logic that doesn't belong in View Controller, is moved up to the Coordinator.